# match_phrase_prefix query for HibernateSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

Is it possible to execute `match_phrase_prefix` in using hibernate search Query? I did not find any appropriate query class so far. I also don't want user   `ElasticsearchQueries.fromJson` since I need to combine different conditions using `bool`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use `ElasticsearchQueries.fromJson`, then no, it's not possible to do that through the Hibernate Search APIs. That's a limitation of the experimental support for Elasticsearch in Hibernate Search 5.

It will be possible in Hibernate Search 6, but it's still an Alpha.